# $f\in C([a,b])$ Each closed subinterval of $[a,b]$ contains an open interval on which $f$ is constant. Is $f$ then constant on $[a,b]$?

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f: [a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continous function. If $\forall [c,d]\subset[a,b]$ there exists an open interval $U\subset[a,b]$ s.t. $f$ is constant on $U$, then can we infer that $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$?
**Motivation**: Some days ago I asked a question: [$f$ real continuous map in $[a,b]$. $∀ x_0∈[a,b], ∃ (c, d) : x∈ (c, d)⊂ [a,b]$ s.t. $x$ is minimum for $f$ in $(c,d)⇒f$ is constant map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4310635/f-real-continuous-map-in-a-b-%e2%88%80-x-0%e2%88%88a-b-%e2%88%83-c-d-x%e2%88%88-c-d%e2%8a%82-a-b-s/4311274?noredirect=1#comment8985140_4311274), and I wonder whether the statement is still true after we weaken its assumption.
**My try on this problem**: I guess the statement is true. To prove it, we assume the contrary. If $a\leq\alpha<\beta\leq b$ and $f(\alpha)\neq f(\beta)$, then we divide $[\alpha, \beta]$ into $[\alpha,\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}]$ and $[\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}, \beta]$. $f$ is not constant on at least one of the two intervals. We then divide the interval on which $f$ is not constant into two equal parts... So we learn that $\exists\eta\in[a,b]$ s.t. $f$ is not constant on any closed interval containing $\eta$, but I do not know how this shall cause contradiction.
**Furthermore**, if the foregoing statement is unfortunately false, what if we strengthen back the assumption: If $f\in C([a,b])$ and $\forall x\in(a,b)$ there exists an open interval $U$ containing $x$ s.t. $f$ is constant on $U$, can we infer that $f$ is constant on$[a,b]$? Applying the same strategy we learn that if we assume the contrary, then (wlog it's $a$) $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $f$ is not constant on $[a, a+\varepsilon]$, but I still can't find contradiction.

Comment: The [Cantor Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is a counterexample.

Comment: Let $N\subset[a,b]$ be a nowhere dense set of positive measure and let $f(x)$ be the measure of the set $N\cap[a,x]$.